# Unity calling singleton which is from another scene without using dontDestroyOnLoad

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton

I have singleton( which is monobehavior also same question for non-monobehavior) which is created at scene 1 , and it created without dontDestroyOnLoad. im calling this singleton from scene 2 , and getting/using the info inside without any problem.I have read something about ghost GameObjects in this case but couldnt find detailed info.

In Scene 1

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RefreshAccount : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static RefreshAccount refreshAccount;
    public string aString = "aaaaaaaa";


    void Awake()
    {
        if (!refreshAccount) refreshAccount = this;
        else Destroy(this.gameObject);
// it is not labeled as DontDestroyOnLoad
    }
(...)
}
```

Scene 2

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class testnewscen : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(RefreshAccount.refreshAccount.aString );
    }
}
```

So will it cause any problem/error in the future of this app ?

Will there be any memory problem or performance problem?

Comment: Well.if it is not `DontDestroyOnLoad` then it will be destroyed when the scene is unloaded ... A bit unclear what exactly you are asking ... Also: is it possible that you already posted 3 similar questions and always go delete them and repost it again? If this is the case please refer to [Is it legit to delete and repost a question that gets no answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305855/is-it-legit-to-delete-and-repost-a-question-that-gets-no-answers)

Comment: When scene 1 is unloaded , i can still reach scene1`s singleton value even though it is not ```DontDestroyOnLoad``` so what im asking is , will it cause some sort of problem for memory or performance ?  I have read somewhere that unity making ghost gameobjects for those but couldnt find detailed info about it

Comment: Well it is a static field so you can access it but it will be null ..  except you make sure somehow somewhere that your object is not destroyed when scene 1 is unloaded .. or do you load the scene 2 additive?

Comment: I load scene 1 first then scene 2 , and it is not null . In scene 2`s script i can get ```Debug.Log(RefreshAccount.refreshAccount.aString )``` result of this , even though scene 1 is unloaded and static doesnt have ```DontDestroyOnLoad ```

Comment: Looks like i cant edit my answer anymore ,so i correct my answer *static doesnt have DontDestroyOnLoad * singleton doesnt have ```DontDestroyOnLoad ```

Comment: I noticed the same behaviour, it's wierd, don't know if it's a feature or a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you use this solution, you cannot run scene 2 without run scene 1 before

If you dont need to set serialize variable / game object / prefabs to your singleton (RefreshAccount) I prefer to use non-monobehaviour singleton instead like

```
public class RefreshAccount {
    private static RefreshAccount instance
    public static RefreshAccount Instance {
        get {
             if(instance == null) {
                 instance = createInstance();
             }
             return instance;
        }
    }

}
```

If you need to use for read some serialize value (variable, config, gameobject, etc.) without behaviour ( awake, update, fix update )
You can use SerializableObject

- SerialzpizeObject is similar static class or prefab but you need to use RESOURCE.LOAD to read it

Comment: scene 1 is main menu, so i have to run scene 1 first to get scene 2 , in this case if i try to call scene 1`s singleton will it cause any performance problem ?

Comment: If not load or initialize new scene is not impact performance too much